# How to add units to a table in R

Tags: r, r-table

I have the following code to create a table in `R`. How can I add unit to `Height` and `Weight` and `BMI`? (so it would be like `Height (in)` and `Weight (lb)` and `BMI (kg/m2)`)

```
Height <- c(66, 73, 65, 68, 71)
Weight <- c(121,191,177,159,152) 
#pound to kilogram and inche to meter
#BMI=kg/m^2
BMI = Weight * 0.45/(Height * 0.02)^2  
expn <- data.frame (Height, Weight, BMI)
knitr::kable (expn, caption = "Body Measurments", align = c ("c", "c"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  all you want to do is add the units to the column names you could use `colnames` and `paste0`.

```
Height <- c(66, 73, 65, 68, 71)
Weight <- c(121,191,177,159,152) 
#pound to kilogram and inche to meter
#BMI=kg/m^2
BMI = Weight * 0.45/(Height * 0.02)^2  
expn <- data.frame (Height, Weight, BMI)
colnames(expn)<-paste0(colnames(expn), c(" (in)", " (lb)", " (kg/m2)"))
knitr::kable (expn, caption = "Body Measurements", align = c ("c", "c"))
```

Table: Body Measurements

| Height (in) | Weight (lb) | BMI (kg/m2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 66 | 121 | 31.25000 |
| 73 | 191 | 40.32182 |
| 65 | 177 | 47.13018 |
| 68 | 159 | 38.68404 |
| 71 | 152 | 33.92184 |

Comment: Does it need extra libraries?

Comment: No it doesn't need extra libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean add units to elements in table,

```
expn <- data.frame (Height, Weight, BMI) %>%
  mutate(Height = paste(Height, "in"),
           Weight = paste(Weight, "lb"),
           BMI = paste(BMI, "kg/m2"))
knitr::kable (expn, caption = "Body Measurments", align = c ("c", "c"))

Table: Body Measurments

| Height | Weight |          BMI           |
|:------:|:------:|:----------------------:|
| 66 in  | 121 lb |      31.25 kg/m2       |
| 73 in  | 191 lb | 40.3218239819854 kg/m2 |
| 65 in  | 177 lb | 47.1301775147929 kg/m2 |
| 68 in  | 159 lb | 38.6840397923875 kg/m2 |
| 71 in  | 152 lb | 33.9218409045824 kg/m2 |
```

In `tibble`,

```
units <- c("in", "lb", "kg/m2")
expn <- data.frame (Height, Weight, BMI)%>% map2_dfc(units, ~set_units(.x, .y, mode = "standard")) 
expn

  Height Weight      BMI
    [in]   [lb]  [kg/m2]
1     66    121 31.25000
2     73    191 40.32182
3     65    177 47.13018
4     68    159 38.68404
5     71    152 33.92184
```

Using `kableExtra`,

```
expn <- data.frame (Height, Weight, BMI)
colNames <- names(expn)
units <- c("$lb$", "$in$", "$kg/m2$")
knitr::kable (expn, caption = "Body Measurments", align = c ("c", "c"), col.names = units, escape = F) %>%
  kableExtra::add_header_above(header = colNames, line = F, align = "c")
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the unit to only the headers and not each individual cell?

Comment: @TinaJ In `tibble` format, I can but after `knitr::kable`, units comes next to values.

Comment: First one gives error: `Error in data.frame(Height, Weight, BMI) %>% mutate(Height = paste(Height,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
Execution halted`

Comment: @TinaJ Oh...I'm really sorry. You may need `library(dplyr)` and `library(units)` for my code.

Comment: @TinaJ There was method using `kableExtra` too. I add that code above.